# OpenVPN "All TAP-Windows adapters on this system are currently in use." error

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, vpn, openvpn

I have been trying to set up OpenVPN on Windows 10 home on my new laptop (64bit). However, I have encountered a problem. I can not connect to any of the VPN servers. When I checked the logs, right before the fatal error was "All TAP-Windows adapters on this system are currently in use.". I used .ovpn files provided by my VPN provider. I also am sure that I am using accurate credentials.

I have re-installed OpenVPN multiple times, making sure TAP adapters were removed and installed again. However, that did not change anything.

When I checked the list of Network connections from the control panel, I found that "TAP-Windows Adapter V9" was recognized as "Unidentified network". Disabling and enabling TAP Adapter from this screen disconnected the adapter from "Unidentified network", changing the status into "Network cable unplugged". In this state, I was able to connect to the VPN. However, if I did not connect to the VPN and wait, TAP adapter quickly went back to being "Unidentified network", preventing me from connecting to the VPN again.

Checking the "TAP-Windows Adapter V9" from the device manager to "Update driver" yielded nothing. Windows stated I already had the best driver.

How can I stop the TAP adapter from being recognized as "Unidentified network"?

Thanks in advance.